# Accessing Android memory at runtime

Tags: android, kernel

I am trying to tinker around with Android framework source and Kernel. I need to know if I wanted to access something like process stack after each Zygote fork, what would be the best way to do it? I tried doing that at Kernel level by means of a Loadable Kernel Module, but then, how to execute that module after every fork? Is there any way to call functions defined in Kernel from the framework source (eg: at dalvik/vm/native/dalvik_system_Zygote.c ) ?
This may seem naive, but I'd appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I kinda figured it out. What I did was defined a new system call in Kernel elf library. That way, I could get the stack address through STACK_TOP. The system call is called after ever fork, which simply returns the stack address value.